# INI4J - Delete Section

Tags: java, ini4j

How can I remove a section with or without the Java library INI4J?

This does not work

```
Wini ini = new Wini(File);
System.out.println(Integer.toString(Position));
ini.remove(Integer.toString(Position));
```

I also tried it with the ConfigParser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code doesn't do anything and definitely does not compile.  Wini is not the correct class, per the ini4j docs you need to instantiate an Ini object and remove/create sections using the Section object.

I would highly recommend reading through the [Ini4J](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html) documentation.  The tutorials are great and the examples provided answer your very question!

Though you can also keep reading too...

Given the Ini File

> [Section]
>
> somekey = somevalue
>
> somekey2 = somevalue2
>
> somekey3 = somevalue3

(Using Ini4J)

We can write

```
Ini iniFile = new Ini(new FileInputStream(new File("/path/to/the/ini/file.ini")));
/*
 * Removes a key/value you pair from a section
 */
// Check to ensure the section exists
if (iniFile.containsKey("Section")) { 
    // Get the section, a section contains a Map<String,String> of all associated settings
    Section s = iniFile.get("Section");

    // Check for a given key<->value mapping
    if ( s.containsKey("somekey") ) { 
        // remove said key<->value mapping
        s.remove("somekey");
    }
}

/*
 * Removes an entire section
 */
if (iniFile.containsKey("Section")) { 
    // Gets the section and removes it from the file
    iniFile.remove(iniFile.get("Section"));
}

// Store our changes back out into the file
iniFile.store(new FileOutputStream(new File("/path/to/the/ini/file.ini")));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did read the JavaDocs. I just couldn't get it to work to remove a section. Again, thank you.